# Read json files in permissive mode - PySpark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a data job to read a bunch of json files, where there is a possibility that few json lines in some files might be corrupt(invalid json).
Below is the code:

```
df = spark.read \
        .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")\
        .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")\
        .json("hdfs://someLocation/")
```

The thing happening for me is that if I try to read a completely perfect file(no corrupt records) with above code, this column is not added at all.

My ask here is to add this "_corrupt_record" column, regardless of whether the json file has corrupt record or not. If a file don't have any corrupt record, all values for this field should be null.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check whether the `_corrupt_record` column exists in `df`, and add it manually if it doesn't.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

if '_corrupt_record' not in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn('_corrupt_record', F.lit(None))
```

Comment: yea, that's one workaround, but is there any option while reading itself, to force that column in ... ?

Comment: @pirate_shady hmm, not that I'm aware of... sorry